# jQuery ajax append html multiple times

Tags: jquery

I've currently encounter some problem, basically I create a few populateModal() functions to populate the modal container with respective html. It works fine for populateModal3 and populateModal4 (same function but with different url value).

ajax returns the data in json and it works perfectly fine in the other two populateModal function.

here's the snippet of the function

```
$.ajax({
                url: "transaction/get_transaction",
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data){
                $('#transModalContainerDel, #transModalContainerEdit').empty();
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {                   
                    console.log('id data: ' + data[i].id);
                    theDelTransModal += 'id modal: ' + data[i].id;
                    //theDelTransModal += '<div id="transModalDel' + data[i].id + '" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteTransaction" aria-hidden="true">';
                    //theDelTransModal += '<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete transaction?</h3></div>';
                    //theDelTransModal += '<div class="modal-body"><p>Are you sure you want to delete this transaction? Note that you can\'t undo this action.</p></div>';
                    //theDelTransModal += '<div class="modal-footer"><a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</a><a href="transaction/delete_transaction/' + data[i].id + '" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete-trans" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</a></div>';
                    //theDelTransModal += '</div>';
                    //$('#transModalContainerDel').append(theDelTransModal);
                    console.log(theDelTransModal);
                }       
            });
```

as you can see from the above code, the returned data is in correct json format. but the id that I try to log return this value.

```
id data: 21 
id modal: 21 
id data: 22 
id modal: 21id modal: 22
```

I'm not sure what went wrong as this function works perfect for the other url.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax success method

```
$.ajax({
                url: "transaction/get_transaction",
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){

$('#transModalContainerDel, #transModalContainerEdit').empty();
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {                   
                    console.log('id data: ' + data[i].id);
                    theDelTransModal += 'id modal: ' + data[i].id;
                    //theDelTransModal += '<div id="transModalDel' + data[i].id + '" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteTransaction" aria-hidden="true">';
                    //theDelTransModal += '<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete transaction?</h3></div>';
                    //theDelTransModal += '<div class="modal-body"><p>Are you sure you want to delete this transaction? Note that you can\'t undo this action.</p></div>';
                    //theDelTransModal += '<div class="modal-footer"><a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</a><a href="transaction/delete_transaction/' + data[i].id + '" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete-trans" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</a></div>';
                    //theDelTransModal += '</div>';
                    //$('#transModalContainerDel').append(theDelTransModal);
                    console.log(theDelTransModal);
                }       
}
            });
```

Comment: hmm, this is what I originally do, now it's working as expected, weird why this doesn't works before.thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

its just because of string joining

```
theDelTransModal += 'id modal: ' + data[i].id;
```

that equal to:

```
theDelTransModal = theDelTransModal+ 'id modal: ' + data[i].id;
```

by removing plus it will be ok.

Comment: damn, that's where I'm wrong, seems like resetting the value right after appending the content to the container works for me, thanks for pointing that out.